# Issue while trying to search using whereBetween in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I have 2 database tables in MySQL below.

**Table - 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblaccount` (
  `account_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(100)
)

ALTER TABLE `tblaccount`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`);
```

**Table - 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblcollectoractions` (
  `collector_action_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_date` date DEFAULT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `tblcollectoractions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`collector_action_id`),
  ADD KEY `tblcollectoractions_account_id_foreign` (`account_id`);
```

I have a query below. It joins records in both tables on the basis of account_id. It also filters those accounts in tblcollectoractions table where pay_date lies between start and end date.

Here is my Laravel Eloquent Query. AccountModel is related to tblaccount and ActionModel is related to tblcollectoractions.

```
$query = (new AccountModel())->newQuery();
$data->whereIn("account_id", function($query) use($inputs) {
    $query->select('account_id')->from(with(new ActionModel)->getTable())
    ->whereBetween('pay_date', [$inputs["from_pay_date"], $inputs["to_pay_date"]]);
});
```

But, this shows me all the records from table tblcollectoractions. I meant, it does not filter on the basis of start and end date.

**Am I missing anything?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the most Eloquent way to do this, checking if the $inputs variable is set

```
$data = AccountModel::query()
->with([
    'actions' => function($query) use ($inputs) {
        if ($inputs['from_pay_date']) {
            $query->whereBetween('pay_date', [
                $inputs['from_pay_date'], 
                $inputs['to_pay_date']
            ]);
        }
    }
])
->has('actions')
->get();
```

the models should look something like this:

AccountModel.php

```
class AccountModel extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ActionModel::class, 'account_id', 'account_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: There are start and end dates. What should I do if the start and end dates are empty? I meant, what if the values are not passed. Can I add any condition in this case ?